# Writing a function that accepts dictionary without specifying key-value

Tags: python

I have a client and his expectation was to write a function `convert()` that accepts a dictionary and then return a result which is the same as input dictionary. Now, from my perspective, I should have to make a checking inside `convert()` that has the same key-value against the input in order to return the same value in order to pass the `assert`. However, he said that was not he expected, he cancelled the contract. He wants `convert()` function to return value without a template for checking (e.g. `if record_id == 412029665_201012` should not be used), what kind of sorcery is this?

```
from typing import Dict


def convert(json_in: Dict) -> Dict:
    if json_in:
        if 'record_id' and 'irs_object_id' in json_in:
            record_id = json_in.get('record_id')
            irs_object_id = json_in.get('irs_object_id')
            if record_id == '412029665_201012' and irs_object_id == '201113199349201766':
                return json_in
    return dict()  # empty dictionary


def test_no_change_case():
    original: Dict = {
        "record_id": "412029665_201012",
        "irs_object_id": "201113199349201766",
    }
    expected: Dict = {
        "record_id": "412029665_201012",
        "irs_object_id": "201113199349201766",
    }
    actual: Dict = convert(original)
    assert actual == expected


test_no_change_case()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do `assert original == expected` which will check if all keys and the corresponding values match, as you can see below, if I change the value for one of the keys of `expected`, or add a new key value pair, the assertion fails

```
In [10]: from typing import Dict                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [11]:  original: Dict = { 
    ...:         "record_id": "412029665_201012", 
    ...:         "irs_object_id": "201113199349201766", 
    ...:     }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [12]: expected: Dict = { 
    ...:         "record_id": "412029665_201012", 
    ...:         "irs_object_id": "201113199349201766", 
    ...:     }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [13]: assert original == expected                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [14]: expected: Dict = { 
    ...:         "record_id": "412029665_201012", 
    ...:         "irs_object_id": "2011", 
    ...:     }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [15]: assert original == expected                                                                                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-573681974ca8> in <module>
----> 1 assert original == expected

AssertionError: 

In [16]: expected: Dict = { 
    ...:         "record_id": "412029665_201012", 
    ...:         "irs_object_id": "201113199349201766", 
    ...:         "key": "value" 
    ...:     }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [17]: assert original == expected                                                                                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-573681974ca8> in <module>
----> 1 assert original == expected

AssertionError
```

Also in your original code, you actually do not need the extra `if 'record_id' and 'irs_object_id' in json_in:` check since you are using the `dict.get` method, which will return None if the key is not present in the dictionary

```
from typing import Dict


def convert(json_in: Dict) -> Dict:
    if json_in:
        #Removed the if test
        record_id = json_in.get('record_id')
        irs_object_id = json_in.get('irs_object_id')
        if record_id == '412029665_201012' and irs_object_id == '201113199349201766':
            return json_in
    return dict()  # empty dictionary


def test_no_change_case():
    original: Dict = {
        "record_id": "412029665_201012",
        "irs_object_id": "201113199349201766",
    }
    expected: Dict = {
        "record_id": "412029665_201012",
        "irs_object_id": "201113199349201766",
    }
    actual: Dict = convert(original)
    assert actual == expected


test_no_change_case()
```

Comment: The task is you shouldn't modify `test_no_change_case()`.

Comment: I just said to him that this is impossible and the task is really horrible.

Comment: then just `assert original == expected` be enough for you! Check my answer for more details @PyHunterMan

Comment: `assert actual == expected` is part of `test_no_change_case()`. This part shouldn't be change. Impossible task.

Comment: I mean to say you can just replace your convert logic to check  `actual == expected ` and pass both actual and expected if you want to ignore value checking, otherwise anything else will be a dirty hack! Also explain to your client that if he knows Python, why not tell you how to do it any other way lol @PyHunterMan